# Avoiding "Unable to register cuDNN/cuBLAS/cuFFT factories" on a CPU-only instance

Tags: docker, tensorflow, gpu, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to serve a model on Amazon SageMaker and thus created a single Docker image for training and inference. The base image used is [tensorflow/tensorflow](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/):2.15.0-gpu.

The endpoint is served on a CPU instance. When the endpoint is being created (the image is run for serving), I get these errors in the logs:

```
E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9261] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered

E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:607] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered

E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1515] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered

E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:274] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (34)
```

And the endpoint fails to be created.

I tried modifying environmental variables, such as `NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`, `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to hide the GPU, but the issue still occurs.

This issue does not exist with a CPU-only tensorflow base image, but I need to use the GPU base image for training purposes. Is there any way of avoiding these errors while using a tensorflow GPU base image on a CPU instance?